# Regression with NA output for external variables

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

I have a data set with multiple variables containing both internal variables (sales, employees, assets, business type, gender, age etc) for 180 companies and some external variables (like GDP, CPI, exports etc.). The data is for three year period, however, when I run regression analysis in R all external factors give NA for all the output variables. What's the best way to resolve this problem. My main intention for the analysis is to ascertain the extent to which both internal external factors impact firm sales. Here is the output

```
Call:
lm(formula = GrowthR ~ LnSales + DistrictDummy + Gendr + 
    EntAge + LnProdctvty + LnTotEmp + LnTotAss + LnCPI + LnDGP + 
    LnExports + LnExR + CorruptionIndex + LnUnemp + LnManSecGDP, 
    data = yr23)
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4134 -0.7780 -0.1118  0.6253 14.7795 

Coefficients: (6 not defined because of singularities)
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -3.261e+00  2.148e+00  -1.518  0.12998    
LnSales         5.635e-01  1.220e-01   4.617 5.48e-06 ***
DistrictDummy   -5.124e-02  3.070e-02  -1.669  0.09602 .  
Gendr            2.905e-01  1.793e-01   1.620  0.10606    
EntAge          -8.668e-03  9.765e-03  -0.888  0.37535    
LnProdctvty        2.315e-08  2.880e-07   0.080  0.93599    
LnTotEmp       -3.423e-01  1.377e-01  -2.485  0.01343 *  
LnTotAss       -6.073e-03  6.657e-02  -0.091  0.92736    
LnCPI          -2.287e+00  8.236e-01  -2.777  0.00578 ** 
LnDGP                  NA         NA      NA       NA    
LnExports                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
LnExR                  NA         NA      NA       NA    
CorruptionIndex      NA         NA      NA       NA    
LnUnemp                NA         NA      NA       NA    
LnManSecGDP       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.461 on 348 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2143,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1963 
F-statistic: 11.87 on 8 and 348 DF,  p-value: 5.627e-15
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this challenge are appreciated!

Comment: Are you using R (since you mention NA)? if so, you may have a level of a factor predictor in your test set that was not present in the training set. In this case, R outputs `NA` for *all* test instances. See [predict.lm() with an unknown factor level in test data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4285214/452096)

Comment: Can you please post your code and output? It's really unclear what you're asking about without seeing this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to add what you now have in comments.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, have just updated the question to include the output from regression analysis

Comment: The error message `6 not defined because of singularities` says your regressors are strongly interrelated (and redundant).  The software has done an excellent job in identifying a minimal number of redundant variables to omit.

Answer (score 1):

@whuber identified the problem: Your variables are collinear. Looking at the names of the variables is also a clue. There are a lot of methods of dealing with this. Some key ones are:

1. Dropping variables. Simply leave some variables out of the regression. Given the apparent strength of the collinearity, this may be best.
2. Getting more data that doesn't exhibit this collinearity. This is probably not going to help in this case.
3. Ridge regression. This allows some bias in the parameter estimates in order to lower their variance. I am not sure if this will work here, but it's worth a try.
4. Partial least squares regression. Sort of like principal components, but it accounts for relationships with the dependent variable.

The above list is not exhaustive.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, will try ridge regression and Partial least squares regression and see if results will be different.